# c++ operator overloading += works but << doesn't work

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I expected that += and << will work the same, but << somehow not working.

here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Pos{
    int x;
    int y;

    void operator+=(Pos vel){
        x += vel.x;
        y += vel.y;
    }
};

struct Obj{
    string name;
    Pos pos;

    void info(){
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << pos.x << ", " << pos.y << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    void operator<<(Pos vel){
        pos += vel;
    }
    void operator+=(Pos vel){
        pos += vel;
    }
};


int main(){
    Pos p{10, 20};
    Obj car{"Car", p};
    Obj truck{"Big truck", {40, 20}};

    car.info();
    truck.info();

    //doesn't work
    car << {0, 10};
    //works
    car += {5, 10};
    //works
    car << Pos{0, 10};
    //works
    car += Pos{5, 10};

    car.info();
}
```

most of them works but 
`car << {0, 10};`

It shows:

```
[Error] expected primary-expression before '{' token
```

I'm wondering what is the difference between `+=` and `<<` and why using constructor will work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How does it not work? Please be specific when asking about code not working.

Comment: Oh sorry I edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This: `{10, 20}` is a braced-init-list. It is *not an expression*. As such, it can appear only [in specific pieces of C++ grammar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

For example, braced-init-lists can appear after a typename, which means they initialize a prvalue of that type. They can appear as an argument to a function. And (among several others) they can appear on the right-hand side of an assignment operator.

Note that `+=` is an assignment operator.

`<<` is *not* one of these specific places. Therefore, a naked braced-init-list cannot appear on either side of a `<<` expression. This is regardless of the fact that the `<<` expression will be converted into a call to `operator<<` and thus the braced-init-list could be considered a function argument. C++ grammar simply doesn't allow a braced-init-list to appear there, so the compiler never gets far enough to even *attempt* overload resolution to figure out which function to call.

Comment: @Ben_TW: As I said "They can appear as an argument to a function." Now look at the last paragraph: "C++ grammar simply doesn't allow a braced-init-list to appear there, so the compiler never gets far enough to even attempt overload resolution to figure out which function to call."

Comment: Read (7) in the reference.

Answer (score -1):

The << operator needs a ostream at lef side. here is .Net version of what you have to do for streaming Date object to "cout":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
    int mo, da, yr;
public:
    Date(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        mo = m; da = d; yr = y;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);
    cout << dt;
}
```

Comment: The OP isn't overloading for streaming.